# Outlook name order

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

Is it possible to have 'Full Name' list as First Middle Last?  Because no matter how many times I change the setting in outlook, when I add a new contact they show Last First without fail.  To be clear I am talking about the FULL NAME not file-as (which is, and should be, Last, First, note the comma), and it doesn't matter if I used the full name dialog box or just type it right in the field.

This is INSANE.  I have spent 30 minutes trying to resolve this with absolutely no luck.  I've never been more sure I was right to totally delete all traces of Office in 2007... now if only I could convince my employer to do the same.

I am sorry to rant but I can't get over this... there is not a man alive (at least using the Roman alphabet) who uses Last First as their standard name order, so why is that the (unchangeable) default for office?

Comment: @GKoe: A version tag for Outlook exists above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have somehow solved this; I changed the default Full Name Order setting, and WITHOUT changing or adding any contacts first, I exited Outlook properly and did a restart.

On restart, I added a new contact.  Again I had the same problem, but about 2 seconds after I added the contact, Outlook automatically switched it to the correct First Last order.

When I did the same thing but made changes in Outlook without restarting it apparently switched my setting back and added the new contact the wrong way.

I don't know what is going on with this, it seems like Office just gets sloppier and sloppier and sloppier.